# No Limit on Sending Individual Emails to Contact, Leads, Person Accounts and Users

Tags: apex-email-service, massemailmessage, singleemailmessage

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm):

> Single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count toward
>   this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts,
>   leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from
>   account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object
>   pages.

Not sure what does this means. Does anybody has any idea about it.
Is it reference to workflow created on these objects, but I can see there is workflow limit. If it is not then what exactly salesforce is trying to say here.

Comment: It is related to email sent by clicking "Send Email" button from the activity related list

Comment: Ohk..thank NickSFDC, I will check and see if there is any change on email limit s and confirm.

Comment: Thanks NickSFDC. This answers my question. So sending individual emails to contact, leads, person accounts and users via activity related list does not consume any limits. Please update this as answer so that others could get benefited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email Limits in Salesforce:

> "Single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count
>   toward this limit. There’s no limit on sending individual emails to
>   contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization
>   directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or
>   custom object pages."

This is applicable to emails sent using the "Send Email" Button on the activity related list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get out https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA or http://www.massmailer.io they should help solve some issues you're having with single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count toward this limit.

I hope this helps solve your problem that you are having.

Cheryl